# Change datetime to number like in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

In jquery I do this:

```
new Date(2009, 12, 1)).getTime()
```

and I got a huge number like this `1262304000000`

How can I change the datetime variable in c# to get the same result that I would get in jquery?

Comment: I am not sure, but you may try this `dateTimeVariable.Ticks`

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript getTime function returns the number of milliseconds since midnight on 1st January 1970.

So to get the same figure from a .NET System.DateTime object, you must subtract the epoch of 1st January 1970 and return the TotalMilliseconds property of the resulting TimeSpan:

```
var dateOfInterest = new DateTime(2009,12,1);
var epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);

var differenceInMilliseconds = (dateOfInterest - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

C# has [`DateTime.Ticks` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) but this doesn't exactly do with [`getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp). Looks like there is no *exactly* equavalent in C#. You can divide result with `10.000` but still it calculates from `0001` year. Javascripts's `getTime()` method calculates from `1970`.

> Gets the number of ticks that represent the date and time of this
>   instance.
>
> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth
>   of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
>
> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001,

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2009, 12, 1);
dt.Ticks.Dump(); // 633952224000000000
```

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds between
>   midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

As a better solution, you can use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure to subtract your dates and use [`TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like;

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 12, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
double miliseconds = (start - end).TotalMilliseconds;
miliseconds.Dump(); // 1259625600000
```

Comment: Please see [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/5) regarding [this tag wiki suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6188011).